# Trouble with finding element by xpath (selenium module in python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am using the selenium module to scrape a website (expedia) in order to retrieve the flight ticket prices.

I am having trouble when I want click an  an element (the search button) to send the information, sometimes it goes well but the majority of the time I get the next exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-action gcw-submit">...</button> is not clickable at point (77, 492). Other element would receive the click: <th scope="col" class="datepicker-day-name">...</th>
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.87)
```

The way that I do is:

First I locate the element by xpath:

```
find = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn-primary btn-action gcw-submit']")
time.sleep(5)
```

Then I click it:

```
find.click()
```

And as I told sometimes this operation is done with success sometimes not.

I am open to any suggestions.

Thank you!

Comment: There is literally somethjng blocking the click. It could be some sort of loader mask. Add an explicit wait where you set the condition to wait for clikablity.

Comment: @pdrersin there is a sleep between those statements, but thank you for the comment, I will try to increase that time.

Comment: I mean sleep may not help. The element could be there but not clickable yet. Use explicit wait like I said. Wait for clicability

Comment: And according to the error log an date picker element might be getting the click. Make sure that you have the correct locator as well.

Comment: WebDriverWait(browser,50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'your xpath')).click()

Comment: This should work if you will try click with JS. I have observed this will not work properly even with explicit wait. Please try it **driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", find)** and let me know.